# MySQL insert column length maximum? (err=Column count doesn't match value count)

Tags: mysql, command-line, hex

I have a table with two cols.  No PHP, just the CLI client.

`create table foo ( id char(36) , obdat blob );`

Cool, now I insert with explicit hex encoding:

```
insert into foo (id,obdat) values ( 'de412530-fb3a-48c7-bfc5-d47ecadc682f'
    , 0x1f8b080035704b580203edbdc98e64c9922 ... f5ff0537186b69cebb0000
);
```

The ellipsis (...) is because this hex length is ~48kB, no newlines.  The mysql CLI client is with `--max_allowed_packet=48M`.  Alas I get the error:

`1136 (21S01) at line 2: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1`

Clearly I have the very same number of inserted columns as the table defines.  **Does the client max at some maximum hex value length?**

Comment: Have you tried shorter hex to test?

Comment: Maybe the interactive mysql client has a limit on the size of a query it will process. But if the line were cut off I'd expect a syntax error.